# Is it possible to know the prime factors of $3+5i$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Let $\mathbb{Z}[i] = \{a+bi : a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(i) = \{a+bi : a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$.
>
> Find $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ such that $(3+5i,1+3i) = (\alpha)$

Since $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a Euclidean domain, every ideal is principal, so $\alpha$ exists and it *is* a greatest common divisor of $3+5i$ and $1+3i$. You could find it with the Euclidean algorithm, but also factorization is possible.

Suppose we know $\alpha$; then $3+5i=\alpha\beta$ for some $\beta$ and therefore
$$
(3+5i)(3-5i)=34=\alpha\bar{\alpha}\beta\bar{\beta}
$$
Since $34=2\cdot 17$, is it possible to know the prime factors of $3+5i$?
If yes, how rigouruously could I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The norm is multiplicative, so if you can factor $3+5i$ the factors must have norms $2$ and $17$.  The only choices (up to units) with norm $2$ are $1+i, 2$ and $2$ is obviously not right, so try $1+i$.  You get $3+5i=(1+i)(4+i)$

Comment: if $(4+i)$, so $(4-i)$ is also a factor, right?

Comment: No, it is not.  Try it. They are not related by multiplication by a unit.  Since $1+i$ is a factor so is $1-i$ because $1-i=i(1+i)$ and $i$ is a unit.